# How to quit delayed_job's lifecycle

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Is there anyway to quit delayed_job's lifecycle in before stage(or any stage) without run perform and without doing anything to the job record in database, just look like never touched it.

Or is there any way to make delayed job avoid touching any job records in databases when given some conditions.

Comment: Why don't you check that condition in your job code/function, and do nothing if the condition is met, else do actual processing.

Comment: @amit_saxena if check in job code, delayed_job process still touched the record, still will update attempts, run_at..., I don't want it to touch it.

Comment: Could you describe in some detail what you are trying to achieve by not changing delayed job record, and what the condition is? I was suggesting that do nothing, and delete the job if the condition is met. Why would you want to keep the job? Do you want to retry later? Is it time sensitive? I would suggest that you rather use 'run_at' for time sensitive delayed_jobs.

Comment: @amit_saxena condition is in a certain time interval and at a certain server(can be identified by hostname), I want to make the delayed job processes not touch the records in database, thanks.

Comment: This can be achieved by using a combination of named queues and 'run_at'. Create named queues per host, and push the job to the particular queue (on the host you want to process) to run at a given time (by setting `run_at`). The workers on each host should be processing only from their particular queue. Read the documentation here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#named-queues

Comment: @amit_saxena this seems a good way, I have a couple of questions about this. 1) Dose it work like this, we start the delayed jobs using RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=host1 start, and when we enqueue jobs we do Delayed::Job.enqueue job, :queue => 'tracking'? 2) Is there anyway don't specify the queue when starting delayed job but put queue name in some configure files so that would be much more convenient when deploying multiple servers?

Comment: Yes, it works that way, and if the queue name is specified while starting a worker, it will process jobs only from that queue. Though do remember to specify the default queue as well (Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name), as the worker without a queue name may process all the jobs (not sure, you need to check). As for specifying queue name in configs, that's possible depending on what you use for deployment. We use capistrano, and the delayed_job start/stop commands are in the recipe file.You can use a combination of 'roles' to have different queues for different workers in start/stop commands.

Comment: You can also put it in monit files (if you use monit to monitor/start the delayed_job daemon). So, it actually depends on how your deployment process works, but is very much possible. In the worst case scenario, if you do is manually, you can create a shell script on each server to start/stop the workers.

Comment: @amit_saxena Thanks a lot, we also use capistrano, and I actually added some keys for each role and defined the queue name there, we use the upstart to do some work like monit, I'm looking into monit, seems it's much more friendly, anyway, thanks a lot!